# Analysis of interaction with multiple levels in each factor (emmeans in mixed model)

Tags: r, mixed-model, interaction, lsmeans

I ran an experiment with `treatment` (3 levels: ctrl, A, B) as a between-subject factor and `environment` (4 levels: 1, 2, 3, 4) as a within subject factor. I have grounds to believe there should be an interaction between these two.

To analyze the data, I am using `lmer` class in R:

```r
> m1 <- lmer(Y ~ environment * treatment + (1 | subjID), data = d)
> anova(m1)

Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                      Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
environment           7.6606 2.55353     3   360 51.2823 < 2.2e-16 ***
treatment             0.9647 0.48237     2   120  9.6874 0.0001258 ***
environment:treatment 0.7344 0.12240     6   360  2.4582 0.0241984 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

So, indeed, there seems to be a significant interaction. Moreover, using `emmeans` it is easy to visualize this interaction is triggered mainly by the different effect of treatment in environment 4:

```
> emmip(m1, environment ~ treatment)
```

[image]

I would like to do analysis of contrasts to show this statistically. I know how to do pairwise comparisons within each level of `environment`, which is easy:

```
> emmeans(m1, list(pairwise ~ treatment | environment), adjust = "holm", 
          lmer.df = "satterthwaite")

$`emmeans of treatment | environment`
environment = 1:
 treatment    emmean         SE     df   lower.CL  upper.CL
 ctrl      0.4180488 0.03909552 426.06 0.34120468 0.4948929
 A         0.5754762 0.03862729 426.06 0.49955241 0.6514000
 B         0.3735000 0.03958120 426.06 0.29570128 0.4512987

environment = 2:
 treatment    emmean         SE     df   lower.CL  upper.CL
 ctrl      0.3526829 0.03909552 426.06 0.27583882 0.4295270
 A         0.4866667 0.03862729 426.06 0.41074289 0.5625904
 B         0.3240000 0.03958120 426.06 0.24620128 0.4017987

environment = 3:
 treatment    emmean         SE     df   lower.CL  upper.CL
 ctrl      0.3078049 0.03909552 426.06 0.23096077 0.3846490
 A         0.4069048 0.03862729 426.06 0.33098098 0.4828285
 B         0.1745000 0.03958120 426.06 0.09670128 0.2522987

environment = 4:
 treatment    emmean         SE     df   lower.CL  upper.CL
 ctrl      0.6570732 0.03909552 426.06 0.58022907 0.7339173
 A         0.6352381 0.03862729 426.06 0.55931431 0.7111619
 B         0.6185000 0.03958120 426.06 0.54070128 0.6962987

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$`pairwise differences of treatment | environment`
environment = 1:
 contrast    estimate         SE     df t.ratio p.value
 ctrl - A -0.15742741 0.05495933 426.06  -2.864  0.0088
 ctrl - B  0.04454878 0.05563390 426.06   0.801  0.4237
 A - B     0.20197619 0.05530587 426.06   3.652  0.0009

environment = 2:
 contrast    estimate         SE     df t.ratio p.value
 ctrl - A -0.13398374 0.05495933 426.06  -2.438  0.0304
 ctrl - B  0.02868293 0.05563390 426.06   0.516  0.6064
 A - B     0.16266667 0.05530587 426.06   2.941  0.0103

environment = 3:
 contrast    estimate         SE     df t.ratio p.value
 ctrl - A -0.09909988 0.05495933 426.06  -1.803  0.0721
 ctrl - B  0.13330488 0.05563390 426.06   2.396  0.0340
 A - B     0.23240476 0.05530587 426.06   4.202  0.0001

environment = 4:
 contrast    estimate         SE     df t.ratio p.value
 ctrl - A  0.02183508 0.05495933 426.06   0.397  1.0000
 ctrl - B  0.03857317 0.05563390 426.06   0.693  1.0000
 A - B     0.01673810 0.05530587 426.06   0.303  1.0000

P value adjustment: holm method for 3 tests
```

but I would like first to say something like "the effect of treatment on Y is different in environment 4 than in the other environments" (basically to test the clear pattern in the figure above). So, what I am struggling with is how to test the general effect of `treatment` within each level of `environment` and how to test if these effects differ across environments.

Moreover, I would then like to test if the "general" interaction is a result of a different effect of treatment A in different environments or the result of a different effect of treatment B in different environments (or both). I can do this easily if I run new models with just subsets of the data but I bet there should be an easy way to all this with the original model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at interaction contrasts; something like this:

```
emm <- emmeans(m1, ~ treatment * environment)
contrast(emm, "eff", by = "environment")           # show the treatment effects
contrast(emm, interaction = c("eff", "pairwise"))  # compare the treat effs
```

This will display, and then compare, the treatment effects (means minus grand means) between environments. (From the graph, the `treatment` effects are all small for `environment` 4, whereas for the other three, the treatment effects are negative for treatments `ctrl` and `B` and positive for treatment `A`.)

You might want something besides `"pairwise"` so as to have fewer comparisons to look at; e.g., `"consec"` will restrict to just consecutive levels of `environment`.

#### Addendum

Here's a more compact approach: First get the effects, then construct a contrast comparing the average of the first 3 environments with the last:

```
emm <- emmeans(m1, ~ treatment * environment)   # as before
trt.effs <- contrast(emm, "eff", by = "environment", name = "trt.eff")
```

At this point we have two "factors" -- `environment` and `trt.eff`; the latter has levels `ctrl effect`, `A effect`, and `B effect`. Now let's contrast these:

```
icons <- contrast(trt.effs, list(`4.vs.123` = c(-1,-1,-1,3)/3), 
                  by = "trt.eff")
summary(icons, by = NULL, adjust = "mvt")
```

These are manually constructed interaction contrasts -- contrasts of contrasts. You could just display `icons` as the three different `by` groups with one contrast each. But if summarized as shown with `by = NULL`, we combine them into one family and apply a multivariate *t* multiplicity adjustment for the family of three tests.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I think your first suggestion compares the treatment effects in between each two environments, but I wanted to say something general about the different effect in 4 vs 1+2+3. Your second suggestion is much more in this direction, but by manually constructing only the comparison of 4 to 1+2+3, I seem to assume that this is the only difference possible, no? Wouldn't I want to compare the effect in each environment to that of all others and see which one is different than the others? Perhaps something like `contrast(emm, interaction = c("del.eff","del.eff"))`?

Comment: Yes, you could do that. BTW, `del.eff` contrasts are proportional to `eff` ones, so in s way it doesn’t matter which you use.

Answer (score 2):

With regard to the first part of your question, i.e.,

> how to test the general effect of treatment within each level of environment

You would need to specify the appropriate contrasts to achieve this. The **emmeans** package seems to offer the possibility to define your own contrasts function; for more info, see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#linfcns).

With regard to the second part, i.e.,

> how to test if these effects differ across environments

if I understand correctly what you mean, I would say that this is the overall interaction effect that you got from the `anova()` function.

Comment: OK on the anova test; but I caution that anova doesn't answer any specific question about *how* things differ.

Comment: Yes, @rvl is right. My question is more with respect to how things differ.